# How do I create a "Read More" button for my blog?

Tags: post, widget, blogs, blogger

I want to make my blog posts appear with a short main page, with a "Read More" button if someone wants to read the whole article.  I tried the code below, but it shows both the short and expanded article on the main page.

1)

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
var thumbnail_mode = &quot;float&quot; ;
summary_noimg = 230;
summary_img = 140;
img_thumb_height = 100;
img_thumb_width = 100;
</script>
<script src='http://blogergadgets.googlecode.com/files/excerpt.js'    type='text/javascript'/>
</head>
```

2)

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<data:post.body/>
<b:else/>
<div expr:id='&quot;summary&quot; + data:post.id'>
<data:post.body/>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
createSummaryAndThumb(&quot;summary<data:post.id/>&quot;);
</script>
<span style='padding-top:5px;;float:right;text-align:right;'><a  expr:href='data:post.url' rel='bookmark'><b>Read more >></b></a></span>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try this one  ?

http://www.bloggerbuster.com/2009/09/how-to-add-bloggers-read-more-function.html

Answer (score 0):

For your reference, I wrote a blog on this feature "[Read more](http://davidchuprogramming.blogspot.ca/2011/06/edit-blogger-html-settings.html)", where there is a section about **Copy Scripts**. Basically, what you need is to update your blogger template with scripts and some HTML codes.